# How to deal with institutions in EU4?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I am playing my first game of EU4 and I came across institutions. The problem is that the Printing Press institution spawned in just one, high development province. The currect projected finish date is 1609. Is there anything I can do to speed up the embracement of the printing press? I tried spending monarch points, but it only helps by a few years since the province is high development already.

Answer (score 3):

1. It's easier to develop your capital - don't hesitate to bump the total development to 30 or 50, it will pay off later.
2. Keep good relations with neighbors who already have it - it will help spread it across the border
3. Ally someone who has it already, they might offer knowledge sharing
4. Wait - it will come to you via natural spread across the Europe, and the projected date doesn't take into account future changes caused by spreading.

Comment: You can also try saving up gold to embrace it earlier, but that's probably sub-optimal.

Comment: @NicolasBudig I would argue on that - waiting for near 100% spread usually means either postponing taking tech, or paying an increased amount of points. Mil tech is always vital, and points are usually more important than money

Answer (score 0):

There are multiples way to spread institutions.

If you have Common sense DLC, you can develop any province to make the institution grow faster. It's the only way to get quickly renaissance and printing press outside of Europe.
Alien-47 advise to develop your capital, while it will not be a waste, it might be more interesting to develop a gem province, or the province with the most bordering provinces.
Beside, If you want to move your capital (there are a lot of reason for doing this), you don't want your capital to be too much developed.

Beside this, there are a lot of spread reason that allow natural grows of an institution. Check the tooltip of the institution spread (or any wiki) to get a list.
For example, the best (and cheapest) way to grow printing press is to have reformed or protestant provinces while yourself also are reformed or protestant.